# google map api draggable route again come to original position

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In google map api when i drag a route, route drags, but when i leave mouse  click route goes to it's old position.
Can anyone tell me what's the reason behind this.

I can't show you all code, But here is some code:-

```
                 var rendererOptions = {
            map: map,
            suppressMarkers : true,
            preserveViewpoint: true,
            polylineOptions:{strokeColor:'blue',clickable:true},
             draggable: true
    };
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

and

```
            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                     if(start!=end)
                     {
                     if (status ==                         google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
                        {
                            directionsDisplay.setOptions({ preserveViewport: true });

                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                            google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed',function () {

                              });
                     }
            }
         });
```

Comment: That isn't the default behavior, it is something your code is doing. Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: But my code is very long and complex. How you understand, If i show you?

Comment: I didn't ask for long and complex code.  I asked for the simplest example you can make that exhibits the problem (hint, I'm not going to look at the code you posted, as I doubt it includes the problem code, and as written it won't even display a map).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. way points has same coordinates when i drag.

Thank you for help